# How can I use auto-py-to-exe on a program that uses selenium? - Chromedriver PATH error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, auto-py-to-exe

Does anyone know how I can use auto-py-to-exe on a program that uses selenium?

I've been dealing with this for a few hours,
I'm getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

This is my code:

```
PATH = r'driver\chromedriver.exe'

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
op.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
op.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=op)
```

It says the chromedriver.exe isn't in the path, but it is?? What am I doing wrong?
I've followed so many red-herring tutorials that didn't work and I'm about to lose my mind over this.

Comment: Are you shipping `chromedriver.exe` with your script?  auto-py-to-exe has no idea you need that external tool.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had to place chromedriver with the .exe file or somewhere like C:\driver\chromedriver.exe so it could be accessible from anywhere on my computer.

Comment: Great answer! Since most IDEs use relative pathing to find chromedriver, the compiler has issues wrapping all the needed files together into a nice package when the file paths are not strictly listed starting from C drive.